# Is there a better way of writing this powershell script?

Tags: powershell

Below is my Powershell script to delete certain backup files on my servers and then display their contents. There is a lot of repetition. Is there a more efficient way of performing this task?

```
Remove-Item \\ietg\z$\Backups\daily\ETG*.bkf -Force -Confirm 
Remove-Item \\icnt\Z$\Backups\Daily\cnt*.bkf -Force -Confirm
Remove-Item \\igre\Z$\Backups\Daily\gre*.bkf -Force -Confirm
Remove-Item \\ihvd\Z$\Backups\Daily\hvd*.bkf -Force -Confirm
Remove-Item \\iklr\Z$\Backups\Daily\klr*.bkf -Force -Confirm

Get-ChildItem \\ietg\z$\Backups\daily\
Get-ChildItem \\icnt\Z$\Backups\Daily\
Get-ChildItem \\igre\Z$\Backups\Daily\
Get-ChildItem \\ivd\Z$\Backups\Daily\
Get-ChildItem \\iklr\Z$\Backups\Daily\
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to keep the data in the same file is to build the hash from two arrays...

```
$servers={"ietg", "icnt", "igre", "ihvd", "iklr"}
$filenames={"ETG", "cnt", "gre", "hvd", "klr"}
$Targets = @{}
if ($servers.Length -ne $filenames.Length) {
    Write-Error -Message "Array lengths do not match" `
                -Category InvalidData `
                -TargetObject $values
} else {
    for ($i = 0; $i -lt $keys.Length; $i++) {
        $Targets[$keys[$i]] = $values[$i]
    }
}
# the rest is from @sysadmin1138's post...
Foreach ($Targ in $Targets) {
    $Child=""\\"+$Targ.Server+"\Z$\Backups\daily\"+$Targ.filename
    $Server=$Child+"*.bkf"
    Remove-Item $Server -Force -Confirm
    Get-ChildItem $Child
}
```

Or, better yet, if the filenames are always part of the servername, you can build the data from one array, like this:

```
$servers={"ietg", "icnt", "igre", "ihvd", "iklr"}
$Targets = @{}
$servers | %{ $Targets.Add( $_, $_.Substring(1,3) ) }
# continue same as above starting from "Foreach ($Targ..."
```

Answer (score 8):

One way is to have the script read in another file for the value pairs. It'll simplify the script, and make maintenance a lot easier.

Input file:

```
Server,filename
ietg,ETG
icnt,cnt
igre,gre
ihvd,hvd
iklr,klr
```

Then something like this (off the top of my head, do not run. Here be errors)

```
$Targets=Import-CSV -File "Input.csv"
Foreach ($Targ in $Targets) {
    $Child=""\\"+$Targ.Server+"\Z$\Backups\daily\"+$Targ.filename
    $Server=$Child+"*.bkf"
    Remove-Item $Server -Force -Confirm
    Get-ChildItem $Child
}
```

The string bulding can almost definitely be done easier. The key thing here is the CSV import and the loop.

If you'd rather do it all in a single file, you can build `$Targets` manually pretty simply:

```
$Targets[0]= @{"Server" = "ietg"; "filename" = "ETG"}
$Targets[1]= @{"Server" = "icnt"; "filename" = "cnt"}
$Targets[2]= @{"Server" = "igre"; "filename" = "gre"}
## and so on
```

Comment: I like this (+1), but it'd be nice to define the data in the same file as the script.

Comment: @JoelCool That's done easily enough. Will amend.